# Prove that $\sum_{cyc}a^4b \ge \sum_{cyc} a$

Tags: inequality

> Let $a,b,c,d>0$ such that $abcd=1$. Prove that the following inequality holds $$\sum_{cyc}a^4b \ge \sum_{cyc} a.$$

The first thing I did was homogenizing the inequality so that I can use AM-GM, $$\sum_{cyc}a^4b \ge \sum_{cyc} a^2bcd $$
But now how can I use AM-GM?
If I used it right away, I’d get $$\sum_{cyc}a^4b \ge 4abcd\sqrt[4]{abcd}$$
Which is not helpful.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you homogenised incorrectly. Homogenising instead gives
$$\sum_{\text{cyc}} a^4b\geq \sum_{\text{cyc}} a^{11/4}b^{3/4}c^{3/4}d^{3/4}$$
Now by weighted AM-GM
$$\frac{133}{204}a^4b+\frac{5}{204}b^4c+\frac{37}{204}c^4d+\frac{29}{204}d^4a\geq a^{11/4}b^{3/4}c^{3/4}d^{3/4}$$
and cyclically adding this inequality and analogous ones yields the result.

EDIT: Here's how to come up with those mysterious coefficients. We want to apply weighted AM-GM such that
$$\alpha\cdot a^4b+\beta\cdot b^4c+\gamma\cdot c^4d+\delta\cdot d^4a\geq a^{11/4}b^{3/4}c^{3/4}d^{3/4}$$
for some $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$ and then cyclically add up this inequality. To make this work, we need
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
4\alpha+\delta&=\frac{11}{4} \\
4\beta+\alpha&=\frac{3}{4} \\
4\gamma+\beta&=\frac{3}{4} \\
4\delta+\gamma&=\frac{3}{4}.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Thus, we solve this linear system and obtain the coefficients from the above solution.

Comment: How did you came up with these numbers?

Comment: I edited the answer so as to include a brief explanation.

Comment: Why you said that I homogenized incorrectly? If I used your method of finding the coefficient with my homogenization, I’d get $\alpha = 23/51, \beta=7/51, \gamma = 11/51, \delta= 10/51$

Comment: @Yassir Can you elaborate on the steps that you took to homogenize? I don't mean the final result (which you have shown), I mean the thinking/reasoning that you used.

Comment: What do you mean? That’s the easiest way to homogenize the inequality? you just multiply by $abcd$ so that the LHS and RHS are on the same degree @CalvinLin

Comment: Sorry I edited the question @CalvinLin